# How to select posts from one category but exclude posts in another category?

Tags: wp-query, categories

I am trying to select posts that have category id `4` but exclude posts that also have category id `2`

Here's what i'm trying

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  "cat__in"         => array(4),
  "cat__not_in"     => array(2),
  "post_type"       => "post",
  "post_status"     => "publish",
  "orderby"         => "date",
  "order"           => "DESC",
  "posts_per_page"  => $limit,
  "offset"          => 0
));
```

However, it's not making the proper selection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cat__in` and `cat__not_in` is not valid parameters. Go and check the valid category parameters in `WP_Query`. You can just simply pass `'cat'=>4` to your arguments to just get posts from category 4. Or as Brad suggested, use `pre_get_posts` and pass the same parameters to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this can be done in 4 separate ways

**Using `cat` with a negative number**

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  "cat" => "4, -2",
  // ...
));
```

**Using `category__in` and `category__not_in`**

I was mistakenly using `cat__in` and `cat__not_in` which are **not** valid WP_Query parameters

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  "category__in"     => array(4),
  "category__not_in" => array(2),
  // ...
));
```

**Using `tax_query`**

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  "tax_query" => array(
    "relation" => "AND",
    array(
      "taxonomy" => "category",
      "field"    => "term_id",
      "terms"    => array(4)
    ),
   array(
      "taxonomy" => "category",
      "field"    => "term_id",
      "terms"    => array(2),
      "operator" => "NOT IN"
    ),
  ),
  // ...
));
```

**Using the `pre_get_posts` filter** (as provided by Brad Dalton)

```
function exclude_posts_from_specific_category($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set("cat", "-2");
  }
}
add_action("pre_get_posts", "exclude_posts_from_specific_category");
```

Comment: Or you could use pre_get_posts

Comment: @BradDalton, a complete answer would be much appreciated. I'm not sure how that would work for me.

Comment: You can alter an existing WP_Query using pre_get_posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to exclude the categories you don't want to display in the loop.

```
function exclude_posts_from_specific_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_specific_category' );
```

Or create a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and use the Category Parameters.

```
<?php

$args = array( 

'category__not_in' => 2 ,

'category__in' => 4 

);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you only want to display posts from one category, you would use the category archive. See [`Template Hierarchy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display).

Comment: Ah, that was my problem. I was using `cat__in` and `cat__not_in`. I needed to use the full word `category` in each parameter. I'm going to tinker with your other method, too.

Comment: I've edited my answer to compile a complete(?) list of methods to do this.

Comment: That's great @naomik. Did you also test your code as well?

Comment: do you mean unit tests? I just ran a quick smoke test to see that each method in my post works.

Comment: Lets leave the commenting here as its dragging out a bit but i simply suggest you test all code snippets in your theme.

Answer (score -3):

Suppose you have posts with cat id 4.

```
query_posts('cat=4');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      the_content();
  endwhile;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** would that solve the problem?

Comment: You should never use `query_posts`, never

Comment: reason for never using query_posts ?

Comment: [This post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) should shed some light on that